# To edit error page 404 in IIS using appcmd.exe commands

Tags: iis-10

I wanted to edit IIS error pages for 404 using appcmd.exe commands. I have attached the command I used and the error I got. Can anyone help me out how to resolve the error.

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "WEBSITE_NAME" -section:system.webServer/httpErrors /+"[statusCode='404',path='/',responseMode='ExecuteURL']"

ERROR ( message:New error object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'error' with combined key attributes 'statusCode, subStatusCode' respectively set to '404, -1'
. )

Comment: `subStatusCode` must be provided, and that's what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpErrors /+"[statusCode='404',prefixLanguageFilePath='YourPath',path='/']" /commit:apphost
```

**Note**: You must be sure to set the commit parameter to apphost when you use AppCmd.exe to configure these settings. This commits the configuration settings to the appropriate location section in the ApplicationHost.config file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This command added a new 404.1 error page setting, but I wanted to edit the existing 404 error page to root folder '/'.

Comment: I edited my answer, or you can also refer to this link: [https://forums.iis.net/t/1233751.aspx](https://forums.iis.net/t/1233751.aspx).